# How do I make svg animation less laggy

Tags: javascript, performance, animation, svg

In [this pen](https://codepen.io/zhirkovski/full/RypQLE) when you hover over a triangle the "hover" outline appears instantly, but the click effect of changing fill colour is really sluggish. esp. in chrome, firefox is better.

is there a better way to do this which would result in instant change of fill colour?

`window.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.target.classList.toggle("active");
})`

Comment: There are too many `use` elements. Use `canvas` instead.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I doubt it. I am pretty sure I have worked with SVGs where 2500 use elements raised no problems with events. to This seems to be with hit-testing (identifing the target element). From a few tests it seems things get better if the **rectangular bounding boxes** of the triangles do not overlap - unfortunate for a hexagonal pattern.

Comment: That's weird.  It takes at least 20s to invoke the click handler when I tested it. That's bad. Obviously there is some bug here.  I suggest you report it to the Chrome team.

Comment: Yeah, its strange. Changing "click" to "mouseover" or "mousemove" makes the fill happen instantly, even when moving across 100's of the triangles